# 'be sick' : defective verb

Tags: ambiguity, defective-verbs

> *George is being sick* means 'George is bringing up food from his
> stomach'; *George is sick* means 'George is ill'. However, *George was
> sick* can mean either George brought up food from his stomach or George was ill.
> Page 422 of Collins English Usage

Is '[be sick](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/be_sick)' a defective verb for which '*George was being sick*' isn't possible?

Comment: I don't know where Collins gets this idea that we don't say *was being sick*.

Comment: *George **was being untruthful** when he said he was too unwell to go to work.* No problem there. Nor is there a problem with *George **was being sick** in the toilet bowl when the phone range* *(**be sick = vomit**)*. But you can't say *George was being sick with polio when he was a child* *(**be sick = be ill**).*

Comment: The 'was being ill' sense of 'was being sick' is not fully available, but the 'was vomiting' sense certainly is. However, 'George was being sick more and more often' could arguably be the 'was being ill' sense. So iterative arguably possible, semelfactive not.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's because _ill_  is an adjective; but for _George was sick_ the only related adjective is _Having an urge to vomit (Synonym: nauseated)_, which is previous to _"vomiting"_ https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sick#Adjective

Comment: According to Google: Sick is the less formal of the two words. It usually describes short-term diseases or ailments, like the flu, and is commonly used to refer to a feeling of nausea. ... Ill is more formal and is used to describe long- and short-term diseases or ailments.

Comment: In Britain, 'sick' can be a noun, meaning 'vomited material', and my father's little joke, when asked what was for supper, was to say "a cup of cold sick". That unappetising dish is sometimes used instead of a "lead balloon" when discussing a frosty reception for an idea.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because The OP has mistaken an adjective for a verb.

Comment: In Britain - at least, in my experience, "sick" is vomit and "poorly" is unwell generally.  Or "ill" if you want to be more formal.  "Sick" to mean unwell was confusing to begin with, and I still have to think twice.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a difference of dialects. “Was being sick” doesn’t sound right to me, an American, and I find precious few hits when I search [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) for `BE being sick`:

- A number of results are just simply gerunds, which are both universally grammatical and not what we’re talking about.
- One result is a Canadian book
- One result is an NBC dateline interview. The woman talking is from London, as reported in [another outlet](http://www.cnn.com/WORLD/9601/indo_ferry/).
- About 10 other hits that I didn’t check the source of.

What I do find idiomatic is “was getting sick”, though this is usually used to mean you’re tired of something and not that you’re actually throwing up. But here’s an example of it referring to someone throwing up, from [NBC](https://profootballtalk.nbcsports.com/2019/12/03/seahawks-overcome-legit-flu-bug/):

> Flowers was able to practice Wednesday, though he was getting sick into garbage cans between plays in practice.

---

In contrast, simply searching Google returns plenty of British articles that use “was being sick” such as [Shops take £800 a second](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-425076/Shops-800-second.html):

> Shopper Helen Nutter, 25, from Morley, West Yorkshire, said: "I have never seen anything like it in my life. A woman was being sick in Next because she's been queuing for so long so she was given a glass of water and looked after by the staff."

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I mean, I would have used the word “dialectical” here if it were reversed: British and American are both dialects.

Comment: "Being sick" sounds quite idiomatic to me (US Midwest).  It's certainly not "formal", but it would be well understood in the proper context.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+being+sick&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3#

Comment: You say, "Was being sick doesn't sound right to me". Don't you say things like "I was driving everyone home from the party, Alice and Bob were getting it together on the seat behind me, Carol was sitting in the passenger seat smoking a joint and Don, having drunk more than anyone else, was being sick in the back, of the van"? Please note that this is a fictional example, not an entry from my diary!

Answer (score 0):

> George is being sick means 'George is bringing up food from his stomach'

**To be sick** is not a verb. **Sick** is an adjective. You can demonstrate this by adding "very" (or some other adverb). George is being **very** (noisily) **sick**.

> George is sick means 'George is ill'.

Like "sick", ill is an adjective.

"George **sicks/is sicking/has sicked** up his food" **Sick** is a verb informal/colloquial.

Comment: The fact that single-word equivalents (vomit, retch, puke, barf) and a recognised multi-word-verb equivalent (throw up) to _be sick_ in the vomit sense exist is a strong argument to single lexeme (multi-word-verb) status.